# How to write this query in VB.Net LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq

Can't figure out how to write this query in LINQ in VB.

```sql
SELECT 
    createdon, SUM(LoggedTime), SUM(cost)  
FROM TimeLedger 
WHERE userid = v_UserId and YEAR(createdon) = v_Year  
GROUP BY createdon 
ORDER BY createdon DESC;
```

Here is my first effort

```
result = (from p in db.TimeLedgers where p.userid=v_userid and year(p.createdon)= p_year group by createdon order by createdon select cost).sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

The GroupBy syntax is a bit weird in LINQ.  I don't have any way to test this, but try this...

```
Dim result = (From p In db.TimeLedgers Where p.userid = v_userID AndAlso p.createdon.Year = p_year
                      Group By p.createdon Into Group
                      Order By p.createdon Descending
                      Select createdon, TotalTime = Group.Sum(Function(v) v.LoggedTime), TotalCost = Group.Sum(Function(v) v.cost))
```

Comment: You left out the `Descending` in the `Order By`, the VB (and C#) syntax for accessing the year member is `.Year`, and you should `Order By` after the `Group` as you shouldn't count on the `Group` preserving the original order.

Answer (score 1):

Using proper VB syntax, and recommended ordering,

```
Dim result = From p In db.TimeLedgers Where p.userid = v_userID And p.createdon.Year = p_year
             Group By p.createdon Into Group
             Order By createdon Descending
             Select createdon, TotalTime = Group.Sum(Function(tl) tl.LoggedTime), TotalCost = Group.Sum(Function(tl) tl.cost)
```